# Ошибка в боте discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord

Выводиться ошибка не понимаю почему
Код:

```
 client.on('message', msg => {
   if (msg.content === '!help') {
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
       .setTitle('Помощь');
       .setColor(0xFF00FF);
       .setDescription('Привет, тебе нужна помощь?');
       .setDescription('Тогда держи!');
       .setDescription('');
       .setDescription(':tada: Развлечения');
       .setDescription('!котик - показывает котика');
       .setDescription('!пёсик - показывает пёсика');
       .setDescription('!кадиллак - без комментариев');
       .setDescription('!relaxmusic - relaxmusic');
       .setDescription('!вочтопоиграть - ...');
       .setDescription('!Орёлилирешка - подбрасывается монетка');
       .setDescription('');
       .setDescription(':shield: Модерация');
       .setDescription('!ban - банит участника');
       .setDescription('!kick - кикает участника');
     message.channel.send(embed);
   }
 });
```

Ошибка:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1054:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1102:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js
```

:71:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47

Comment: А ошибку кидать не надо...

Comment: Всё я написал ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Ну во первых зачем столько вызовов метода `setDescription`?
А синтаксическая ошибка связана с тем, что Вы пытаетесь вызывать методы от `MessageEmbed()`, но получается что то такое:

```
const embed = new MessageEmbed().setTitle('Помощь');.setColor(0xFF00FF);...
```

То есть, после вызова каждого метода, *(setColor,setTitle...)* не нужно ставить ';'.    Ни в коем случае не JS разработчик, но все таки множественные вызовы `setDescription` бесполезны.

Comment: Спасибо, icYFTL